# smartGWT date input validator

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I'm using `DateTimeItem` for my start and end dates. I don't want the user to be able to select invalid dates, like `13/44/2014`:

First image is a example of valid date, the second (one below) is a invalid date.

[image]

How do I avoid the second one from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [CustomValidator](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/validator/CustomValidator.html).

Sample code:

```
final DateTimeItem dateTimeItem = new DateTimeItem();
final DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
final DateDisplayFormat dateDisplayFormat = DateDisplayFormat.TOUSSHORTDATE;

dateTimeItem.setDateFormatter(dateDisplayFormat);
dateTimeItem.setTitle("Date");
CustomValidator dateValidator = new CustomValidator() {

    @Override
    protected boolean condition(Object value) {
        try {
            // An exception is throws if an invalid date is entered
            dateTimeFormat.format((Date) value);
        } catch (Exception e) {                
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

};
dateValidator.setErrorMessage("Invalid date");
dateTimeItem.setValidators(dateValidator);
dateTimeItem.setValidateOnChange(true);
```

snapshot:

[image]

---

Alternatively try with [ChangedHandler](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/events/ChangedHandler.html).
Same issue is addressed here on SmartGWT forum.

- [How to validate DateTimeItem data (if user enters wrong syntax for date or time)?](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=23373)

Sample code:

```
    final DateTimeItem dateTimeItem = new DateTimeItem();
    dateTimeItem
            .addChangedHandler(new ChangedHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ChangedEvent event) {
                    try {
                        // An exception is throws if an invalid date is entered
                        dateTimeItem.getValueAsDate();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        SC.say("Invalid Date");
                    }
                }
            });
```

---

If you are looking for Date Range then try with [DateRangeItem](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/DateRangeItem.html) that allows a user to select an absolute or relative range of dates via two [RelativeDateItem](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/RelativeDateItem.html)s (if [allowRelativeDates](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/DateRangeItem.html#getAllowRelativeDates%28%29) is true) or two [DateItem](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/DateItem.html)s.

Sample code:

```
    DateRangeItem dateRangeItem=new DateRangeItem();
    dateRangeItem.setFromDate(fromDate);
    dateRangeItem.setToDate(toDate);
    dateRangeItem.setValue(new DateRange());
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Braj I am using CustomValidatod method. When I go to enter a date, it also asks me to enter the minute and seconds field as well. Is there a way disable those? I dont want to ask the user to enter minute and seconds. Thanks!

Comment: try with my code that where it accept only date. try with `setDateFormatter()`. I don't know I how you validating it?

Comment: I used setDateFormatter and set it to DateDisplayFormat.TOUSHORTDATE.
This is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/71r1lr4.png  Asking to enter the min. and seconds field as well. @Braj

Comment: Sorry I don't have any idea about masking? I'll try it later if found any solution then I'll tell you.

Comment: Yes I do have setUseMask set to true @Braj

Comment: Quick question @Braj, sorry. what is the specific Exception being thrown in try {dateTimeFormat.format((Date) value);} ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the string that a user typed in this field and check if this is a valid date.

For example:

```
public static Long parseDate(String value) {

    try {
        Date date = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_SHORT).parseStrict(value);
        return date.getTime();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    }

    try {
        Date date = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_MEDIUM).parseStrict(value);
        return date.getTime();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    }

    try {
        Date date = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_LONG).parseStrict(value);
        return date.getTime();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    }

    try {
        Date date = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_FULL).parseStrict(value);
        return date.getTime();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: the value here is String type. I have a DateTimeItem startDate, how do I convert this to string so I can use strictParse()?